# R: use forecast::accuracy() on split data

Tags: r, forecasting, cross-validation

Having a hard time getting the `accuracy()` function from `{forecast}` to work on predicted test values.

First, build the LM model on the training data (here for reproducibility):

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
train <- sample(392, 196)
lm.fit <- lm(mpg~horsepower, data = Auto, subset = train)
```

Then compute the MSE of the test data:

```
mean((auto$mpg - predict(lm.fit, Auto))[-train]^2)
```

My goal is to use `forecast::accuracy()` to get MSE (rather than the above) and additional measures of error. However, I simply can not get it to run, no matter what I feed it. This is definitely user error, and looking for any thoughts out there.

I know `forecast::accuracy()` does not contain MSE "out of the box" but I plan on computing it via `accuracy(data)[, 2]^2` and merging with the other output.

Comment: Why do you want to use `forecast` that is for time series?

Comment: I like the multiple measures of error `forecast::accuracy` produces. The help documentation states `accuracy()` can take `LM` objects, so believe this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
accuracy(forecast(lm.fit, newdata=Auto[-train,]), Auto$mpg[-train])[,2]^2
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. I kept messing up the second argument to `accuracy()`.